# Error in building android app using cordova

Tags: android, maven, cordova, build, build.gradle

When I run the command 'cordova build android' , the following error occurs:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/2.1/android-maven-gradle-plugin-2.1.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/2.1/android-maven-gradle-plugin-2.1.pom'.
  >   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
  >   Could not resolve com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/2.1/android-maven-gradle-plugin-2.1.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/2.1/android-maven-gradle-plugin-2.1.pom'.
  >   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
  >   Could not resolve com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/2.1/android-maven-gradle-plugin-2.1.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/2.1/android-maven-gradle-plugin-2.1.pom'.

Comment: Do you have any corporate proxy between you and the public maven repositories?

Comment: no any corporate proxy